# What is AT Command for Voice Message to be here by Call Receiver in form of .Wav file?

Tags: c#, .net, phone-call, at-command, modem

I have a Voice modem D-Link and I am communicating with it over a serial connection with AT commands. I am trying to put the modem in voice mode so that I can dial a number through AT Command ATD and play a wav file that should be heard on the receiving end. I do not know the commands to put the modem into voice mode.

Comment: Read the modem manual.  The AT command will be list in the documentation.

Comment: Searched A lot but :,(

Comment: What model to you have?  Did you check the support page : https://support.dlink.com/

Comment: I have model d-link dwm-157

Comment: On the list of model in the download I do not see the model.

Comment: Nothing happened .

Comment: Looks like 157 is an older model.  Newer model is a dwm-311.  It looks like the dwm is just a dumb Wifi device that connects the local machine to a remote devices through RF.  You need to get the model of the actual device on far end of the which has commands.

Comment: I am using it for SMS and Call System purposes via C# Code.

Comment: It appears all the DWM is a WiFi Transmitter and Receiver to remote control devices not directly connected to the PC.  Not an SMS Modem.  The SMS Modem must be a different part number either connected to the PC directly or to the DWM Receiver.